AR.js 3D model Draco decompression issue
I am trying to decompress a Blender compressed .glb 3D model. I believe I'm having issues decompressing the file. Chat GPT has me referencing a draco loader script (script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three/examples/js/loaders/DRACOLoader.js"). I also have downloaded the following 3 files to my folderpath:
 draco_decoder.wasm
 draco_wasm_wrapper.js
 draco_decoder.js

If I use a 3D model which isn't compressed in Blender (phone.glb for example) this code works, but the moment I have a Blender compressed model (phone2.glb for examlpe) it dosen't work.
Any help would be very much appreciated! I'm trying to compress a memory heavy 3D model that way I can use it on my web application.
Here is the code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <!-- we import arjs version without NFT but with marker + location based support -->
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
    <!-- Add Draco loader script -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three/examples/js/loaders/DRACOLoader.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
    <a-scene embedded arjs>
     <a-marker type="pattern" url="https://bg.com/AR/hiro.patt">
        <a-entity
          position="0 0 0"
          scale="0.05 0.05 0.05"
          rotation="0 0 0 "
          gltf-model="https://bg.com/AR/phone2.glb"
          animation__rotation="property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; loop: true; dur: 5000"
          draco-decoder="https://bg.com/AR/draco_decoder.wasm"
        ></a-entity>
      </a-marker>
      <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>

I've tried downloading different draco_decoder.wasm files but that hasn't helped.
